# Pickup call automatically in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

What exactly I need is that when an incoming call come and my app is in foreground than the call must be automatically received and loudspeaker must be activated.

I have seen many post in SO saying that to intercept the calls is not possible in iOS.

But what if I use any VoIP API and make calls from it to my app[app to app call] ?

can I receive the call automatically in that case or that time also the SDK won't allow me to do so as its the core part of iOS I am too much confused.

Comment: what VoIP API are you considering that allows you to hook into an incoming call?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann thanks for the reply , I have seen API like sinch that is paid. But I am not sure that they will allow me to do so. as well as the sdk will allow or not.  SO any API will not allow me to intercept their calls too ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with UIKit, and furthermore if you did use private Apis your app would not be approved.